# How to make a backup virtual machine

Tags: linux, backup, virtualization, snapshot, ovirt

Can we use a virtual machine (Machine A) to take the backup of another **virtual machines snapshot**(Machine B). If we can do it what setup should we make (in machine A). Can you give me a working example with some real virtualization techniques.Assumption is that both the virtual machines are running on some cloud virtual machine management services for example like ovirt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is a general question, I think the feature you are really looking for is snapshots. 
I use a lot of cloud based VMs, most cloud provider offer you to snapshot your volumes, this is the preferred way to do backups in the cloud as it doesn't require you to stop or slow down your VM the back up is done at the disk level. 
Later on you can restore your backups by creating an image out of your disk snapshots and spinning a new VM with this image.

On the other hand if you really need to backup a running at the filesystem level, you can have a look at rsync on linux/unix hosts. For Windows sorry I don't have a clue...

Comment: @zuperben.I could take a snapshot of the vm(machine A).I used an external api to take the snapshot.but the major difference between snapshot and backup according to my understanding is that you cant backup a vm using snapshot if the parent machine is corrupted.The snapshot i made is in the same vm(A) as the vm i need to backup(machine A). But the api spec mentions that " Attach the snapshot to the backup virtual machine and activate the disk:". any idea on how to attach the snapshot to the backup virtual machine (machine B)..Any idea what they mean by this backup virtual  machine. (machine B)